# Retrieve memory usage and CPU usage from jvm

Tags: java, memory, jvm, cpu-usage, memory-footprint

I want to write java code to get Memory and CPU usage of a Java server thats run on local host. It's better if I can get values by PID (process ID) like in jconsole. How can I do that? I'm new to Java and I have less experience about these things.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/ManagementFactory.html

Comment: Using `jstat` might be simpler.  It gives you the stats every N seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Writing java code may not give you accurate results because too much of this measuring code before and after methods might add to the memory and cpu usage that you're trying to monitor.

You can use

(1) jVisualVM in JDK6 or above to monitor CPU and memory usages of each thread in that server
(2) Java Flight Recorder of Java Mission Control in JDK7/8

Both these options come with JDK by default and you can find them in JAVA_HOME/bin directory.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [javamelody](https://code.google.com/p/javamelody/)?

And [here](http://demo.javamelody.cloudbees.net/monitoring) is a demo.